# Show that the series diverges $1 + \frac{3}{2} +\frac{9}{4} + \frac{27}{8} +\frac{81}{16}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Show that the series diverges $$1 + \frac{3}{2} +\frac{9}{4} + \frac{27}{8} +\frac{81}{16}+\cdots$$

The numerator is increasing at a rate of $3a_n$ and the denominator is simply doubling $2b_n$

Naturally this series will diverge since it will increase to infinity since the numerator is growing faster than the denominator.

Is there a more robust way of illustrating this?

Comment: To show the divergence it is sufficient to consider that every summand (except the first) is greater than $1$

Comment: I assume you are only looking for convergence in the reals, because that series converges to $-2$ in $3$-adic numbers.

Comment: Multiple routes on this one, limit test shows that not only does the sum diverge, but also the sequence of summands. You could also show this by comparing with the series 1+1+1+1+1...

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test); the ratio of consecutive terms is $\frac32>1$. You could also use [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tail_of_Convergent_Series_tends_to_Zero) theorem.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$1 + \frac{3}{2} +\frac{9}{4} + \frac{27}{8} +\frac{81}{16}+...=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac32\right)^n$$

and $a_n \to \infty$ therefore the series diverges, indeed recall that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n <\infty \implies a_n \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

For a series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. Then by definition, the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ converges if and only if the sequence $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ converges. Now we can easily prove the following:

> If the sequence of terms $\{a_i\}$ does not converge to $0$, then the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ diverges.

Proof: if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ converges to some $L$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $|S_n-L|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. In particular, $|a_{n+1}|= |S_{n+1}-S_n|\le |S_{n+1}-L|+|L-S_n|<2\varepsilon$, so $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$.

Applying this to your example, the series diverges since $\left\{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^i\right\}$ does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

This is the series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)^n$$

this is a geometric series, to what sum does the general term converges a n goes to infinity